# Does $x_n\sim y_n\implies \sum_{n\geq 1}x_n\sim\sum_{n\geq 1}y_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x_n,y_n\geq0$ for all $n$. I know that if $x_n\sim y_n$ and that $\sum_{n\geq 1}y_n$ converge, then $\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n$ converge. But to me, it doesn't imply that $\sum_{k\geq 1}^nx_k\sim\sum_{k=1}^n y_k$, take for example $x_n=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Now I have that $$f_n(k,p)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ and $$\rho_\lambda(k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}.$$ I have shown that if $$f_{n}(k,p_n)\sim_\infty \rho_\lambda(k)$$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty }np_n=\lambda$. Now, have to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty } \sum_{k=1}^n kf_n(k,p_n).$$

In the correction it's written that since $f_n(k,p_n)\sim_\infty \rho_\lambda(k)$, we conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty } \sum_{k=1}^n kf_n(k,p_n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=\lambda.$$

I don't really understand why the fact that $f_n(k,p_n)\sim_\infty \rho_\lambda(k)$ imply that $$\lim_{n\to\infty } \sum_{k=1}^n kf_n(k,p_n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}.$$

**Don't answer that a binomiale can be approach by a poisson law if $n$ is big a $p$ very small. I know this and it's not my question !**

Comment: Where does this come from -- is it a textbook?

Comment: What does $x_n\sim y_n$ mean?

Comment: @5xum Landau notation, I assume: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Answer (score 0):

You are right for the fact that $x_n\sim y_n$ and that $\sum y_n$ converge doesn't implies $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \sim_n \sum_{k=1}^n y_k$, in this case, you have the equivalence $\sum_{k=n}^\infty x_k \sim_n \sum_{k=n}^\infty y_k$.

For your problem, I might be wrong, but I think you can pose
$\phi_n(k) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} f_n(k, p_n) & if\quad k\leqslant n\\
0 & otherwise\end{array}\right. $ and write the sum as $$ \sum_{k=1}^n kf_n(k,p_n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\phi_n(k)$$

by hypothesis you have  $\phi_n(k) \to \rho_\lambda(k)$ for all $k$, so you might be able to invert the limit to conclude $$  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n kf_n(k,p_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\phi_n(k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}k\phi_n(k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho_\lambda(k)$$